# how do I center the 4 boxes inside grid container so they would resize equally?

Tags: html, css

I tried centering them using margin but it still doesn't fix the resizing issue.
I need the four boxes to be in the center of the red container.
Right now, the boxes and their container don't resize equally.
Container becomes either larger or smaller than the boxes.
I need some room between the boxes and the container also between the boxes themselves.

**CSS**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 50%;
  background: Crimson;
  margin: 40% auto;
  gap: 4px;
  grid-template-areas: "first second" "third  forth";
  grid-template: 48% 48% / 48% 48%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: grid;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.box {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px #a11d33;
  background: #ED365B;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover {
  background: #ff4d6d;
  color: #800f2f;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: grid;
  padding-bottom: 44%;
}

.first {
  grid-area: "first";
}

.second {
  grid-area: "second";
}

.third {
  grid-area: "third";
}

.forth {
  grid-area: "forth";
}
   
**HTML**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="myCSS.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="box first">
      First
    </div>
    <div class="box second">
      Second
    </div>
    <div class="box third">
      Third
    </div>
    <div class="box forth">
      Forth
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```